# Is it better to run voice, data and tv cables in separate conduit?

Tags: networking, ethernet, tv, cable

I'm hoping to run new phone, ethernet and coax cables. As it turns out, I'll also be running 3 conduit runs from the distribution point to the attic. Is there a **significant** benefit to running the cables in their own conduit? One conduit all data, one all phone the other all rg6?

The one big draw back is it will take longer to pull the cables and I'll have to spend a lot of time sorting through the cables in a cramped attic space.

6 wall plates are getting wired through the conduit and they're sort of paired by location. My thinking was to pull two bundles through each conduit that I can then separate and lead to their respective wall plates. I'm even planning on building this [cable reel](http://tombuildsstuff.blogspot.com/2014/02/homemade-wire-caddy.html) (link to my article) so that I can pull each conduit in one shot.

Phone will be analog (Cat6), data with be gigE (Cat6), tv lines will be OTA (RG6 quad shield), satellite to some plates and then maybe cable or fios down the road if that matters.

I know people combine data cables in conduit all the time but just wondering if it could cause degredation of signals or limit me from using certain technology (PoE for example) in the future.

Comment: Sounds like the more time consuming process would be the better choice

Comment: There's no way to confirm my credentials or anything here... and it's a little late in the night for me to post an answer with the technical details ;). So suffice it to say, short answer: No, not worth it. As long as you're not cramping the cables together (i.e., zip tying them through the conduit), you're going to be fine. We ran 20+ cables through a single opening, with little issue.

Comment: @ctote that's kind of what I was thinking but if you ever have time to post the details I'd be interested in reading them. I planned my conduit so all the runs will have less than a 40% conduit fill so the cables won't be cramped and per TIA/EIA recommendation. One thing I was thinking is that if HDBaseT ever comes to the consumer market and I get HDBaseT TVs it might be a problem but that would be true with seperate voice, data, tv runs unless I used the phone cables for HDBaseT instead of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, there is nothing wrong with running all three in the same conduit as long as the conduit is large enough to accommodate. None of these type of cables have any significant voltage. Just do not run power lines with data or phone lines.